# Why not all headers can be found in fetch's response?

Tags: javascript, httpresponse

I'm trying to intercept `Set-Cookie` [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/entries) from `fetch`'s response:

```js
fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png', {
 method: 'get'
}).then(function(response) {
    for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {
        console.log(`${pair[0]}: ${pair[1]}`);
    }
});
```

But not all of the headers (as can be seen in developer tools' network) can be found in there! Why is that? Is there any way I can get the header I'm looking for?

Just for clarification, I'm not looking for the cookie but I'm interested to know when the `Set-Cookie` header is sent.

Comment: `Fetch API cannot load https://google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.google.com' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: @guest271314 That's because I could not find any website with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. If you know any, please tell me.

Comment: Use `"/"` as URL at the current Question at `console`

Comment: @guest271314 Does not help, it leads to the same error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read the `Set-Cookie` header as it is declared as forbidden. The `fetch` polyfill on github provides a reasonable explanation:

> Like with XMLHttpRequest, the Set-Cookie response header returned from
>   the server is a forbidden header name and therefore can't be
>   programatically read with response.headers.get(). Instead, it's the
>   browser's responsibility to handle new cookies being set (if
>   applicable to the current URL). Unless they are HTTP-only, new cookies
>   will be available through document.cookie.

https://github.com/github/fetch#receiving-cookies